# Android Emulator screen is corrupt and stretched

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator, emulation

I have been trying to get **android emulator** to work in a **GCloud server instance** with **Ubuntu 18** installed, with KVM and virtualization settings are all done properly.

Because the server does not have an actual gpu, I am using `-gpu swiftshader_indirect` and forcing it to use software based rendering mode, i.e cpu instead of gpu.

Right after the emulator boots up, the view is in green and pinkish colors with overly stretched resolution. This both looks bad and prevents me to use it, please see the attached image below.

### [Please see the image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK9is.jpg)

I had also had problems to get a proper view of the whole Ubuntu Desktop UI with using VNC Viewer, and kinda hacked some startup config file to get things proper (not sure If I did everything correct), could this be related to it all? Apart from the emulator screen, I have no problems elsewhere on the system UI though